# How can I edit itunes song lyrics from the terminal?

Tags: applescript, itunes, osascript

I can get the lyrics using:

```
osascript -e '''tell application "iTunes" to lyrics of the current track'''
```

but how can I set them?

I'm trying to make corrections to the current lyrics using my text editor.

Comment: Have you tried "set lyrics"? I think that's it.

Answer (score 2):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to set lyrics of current track to "hoho"'
```

Thanks to regulus6633

And as a cli script

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript
-- update_lyrics <track persisten ID> <lyric file>

on run argv
    try
        set trackPersistentID to item 1 of argv
        set lyricsFile to item 2 of argv

        -- use awk to strip leading empty lines
        set cmdString to "cat " & lyricsFile & " | awk 'p;/^#+$/{p=1}'"
        set newLyrics to do shell script cmdString
    on error
        return "update_lyrics <trackID> <lyricsFile>"
    end try

    tell application "iTunes"
        set mainLibrary to library playlist 1
        try
            set foundTrack to (first file track of mainLibrary whose persistent ID = trackPersistentID)

            set lyrics of foundTrack to newLyrics

        on error err_mess
            log err_mess
        end try
    end tell
end run
```